# SWT StyledText Widget - WhiteSpace Painting

Tags: swt, paint

I have a `StyledText` widget in an SWT app with formatted text like so:

```
Type                 -> Text
MessageID            -> ID:205871803-172.30.227.122(89:ab:da:58:b9:f3)-32849-1332173293715
CorrelationIDAsBytes -> [B@d1c778
Expiration           -> 0
Priority             -> 4
Timestamp            -> 1332173293715
Redelivered          -> false
```

However, this is what it ends up looking like:
[image: SWT StyledText Weird Whitespace]

Is there some option I can turn on to make it display the whitespace "as is"?

I tried adding some style to it to get it to look right, but it still doesn't work:

```
        _messageDataText.addLineStyleListener( new LineStyleListener() {
            public void lineGetStyle( final LineStyleEvent lineStyleEvent ) {
                StyleRange styleRange = new StyleRange();
                styleRange.start = 0;
                styleRange.length = _messageDataText.getText().length();
                styleRange.font = new Font( Display.getCurrent(), "Arial", 12, SWT.NORMAL );
                lineStyleEvent.styles = new StyleRange[] {
                    styleRange };
            }
        } );
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently it depends on the font. If you use "Courier New" instead the whitespace lines up properly.

This is what I changed:

`styleRange.font = new Font( Display.getCurrent(), "Courier New", 10, SWT.NORMAL );`

Also, as a side note - it is important to reuse fonts wherever possible or you'll get nasty handle problems.